# Mapping objects by means of map function in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapping

I want to understand:

- Why exec_query returns an array with object when mapped by map function?
- How does the assignment to id and nome variables happen by means of map function?

I have this code:

`produto = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT * FROM produtos")`

Return of produtos

```
#<ActiveRecord::Result:0xb774bc8 @columns=["id", "nome"], @rows=[[1, "yuri"], [2, "Igor"], [3, "Iran"], [4, "Hotaviano"], [5, "Maria"], [6, "José"], [7, "Mateus"], [8, "kaun"]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>
```

When I do this:

```
produto.map { |p| Produto.new(p) }
```

It returns the following:

```
[
  #<Produto:0xad8fd60 @id=1, @nome="yuri">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fbe4 @id=2, @nome="Igor">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fbd0 @id=3, @nome="Iran">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fb1c @id=4, @nome="Hotaviano">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8facc @id=5, @nome="Maria">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f9b4 @id=6, @nome="José">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f9a0 @id=7, @nome="Mateus">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f784 @id=8, @nome="kaun">
]
```

Comment: Apologies for being nit-picky, but `map` is not a function. It is a method. And, according to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), it "creates a new array containing the values returned by the block." So, to your first question, the `map` method returns an array of `produti` because an instance of `Produto` is the value returned by the block.

Comment: And the sencond question. @jvillian

Comment: Hold on, what are you trying to do? `Produto.all` does the same thing if you're trying to initialize a bunch of ActiveRecord objects. (You use `exec_query` to save time/memory re: initializing AR objects, which you do anyway. Is that your intention?)

Comment: Hi @DaryllSantos, I wanna understand why does produto.map { |p| Produto.new(p) } returns me this:
[
  #<Produto:0xad8fd60 @id=1, @nome="yuri">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fbe4 @id=2, @nome="Igor">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fbd0 @id=3, @nome="Iran">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8fb1c @id=4, @nome="Hotaviano">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8facc @id=5, @nome="Maria">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f9b4 @id=6, @nome="José">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f9a0 @id=7, @nome="Mateus">, 
  #<Produto:0xad8f784 @id=8, @nome="kaun">
]

Comment: Check it out here: [ActiveRecord source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L299-L302). You have a bunch of hashes from `exec query`, and you initialize the ActiveRecord object (`Produto`) after. Now that works if you want to use the ActiveRecord methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for being nit-picky, but `map` is not a function. It is a method. And, according to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), it

> creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

So, to your first question, the map method returns an array of `produti` because an instance of `Produto` is the value returned by the block.

To your second question, the `map` method, using `@columns`, is creating a `hash` (`p`) like:

```
{id: 1, nome: 'yuri'}
```

For each entry in `@rows` which is then used to instantiate each instance of `Produto` when you do `Produto.new(p)`.

Try:

```
produto.map do |p| 
  puts p
  Produto.new(p)
end
```

to check it out.

Comment: So map method connects columns for each entry in rows, in the following way:

columns=["id", "nome"] with row[0] = [1, 'Yuri'] ----> { "id" => 1, "nome" => "Yuri"}
columns=["id", "nome"] with row[1] = [2, 'Igor'] ----> { "id" => 2, "nome" => "Igor"}
columns=["id", "nome"] with row[2] = [3, 'Igor'] ----> { "id" => 3, "nome" => "Iran"}
...
columns=["id", "nome"] with row[n] = [100, 'Hotaviano'] ----> { "id" => 100, "nome" => "Hotaviano"}, right @jvillian ?

Comment: See what happen when I use debugger: https://gist.github.com/Yuridsm/8982c3f0f745607b195795828f74232f